# jQuery var to equal the value of the input box that it is focused on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a dynamic small lenght converter that contains 3 input[text]s. Like so

```
<input type='text' class='bx' id='cm'> Centimeter<br>
<input type='text' class='bx' id='m'> Meter<br>
<input type='text' class='bx' id='km'> Kilometer<br>
```

The effect is the following: if you click on "Meter" the value becomes '' and if you type a value the "Centimeter" and "Kilometer" value will be equal to a value(...).

[Example](http://calculator.com/calcs/conv.html)

The jquery is like so:

```
$(function() {

var selected = ????;

// do i need something here to empty the input it is focused on?

$("#cm").val(selected * 545);
$("#km").val(selected * 545);
$("#m").val(selected * 453);

})
```

I want the var selected to be equal to the value of the text input it is focused on.

How can i do this?

**The calculation in examples are informative.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var selected = $(this).val();
```

//  // The code you have written will only work fro the first time your page loads. If you want it to work on every click of it you need to handle the focus event of the input..

```
 $('#cm , #km , #m').on('focus', function() {
        var selected = parseInt($(this).val() , 10) ; // Will convert to a Int

        $("#cm").val(selected * 545);
        $("#km").val(selected * 545);
        $("#m").val(selected * 453);

    });
```

But I think a **blur** event makes more sense here instead of a **focus** event..

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/CAxBr/1/)

Which will point to the value of the selected input

Comment: thanks this is helpful but in your example the input values dont chance as in the example that i have given

Comment: I have used blur event in the example.. So as soon as you type in something and the input loses focus you can see the change

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery focus to get selected input field.

```
 $(function() {
         $("input.bx").focus({
          var selected  =parseInt(this.value, 10);
              this.value = ''; //this line will remove text from selected input.
              $("#cm").val(selected * 545);
              $("#km").val(selected * 545);
             $("#m").val(selected * 453);
         });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a listener that listens for the focus event.

check this out:

http://api.jquery.com/focus/

```
$('.bx').focus(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if (id === "cm") {
        alert('Handler for .focus() called cm');
    }
    else if (id === "m") {
        alert('Handler for .focus() called m');
    }
    else if (id === "km") {
        alert('Handler for .focus() called km');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an event handler, in this case for the [`focus` event](http://api.jquery.com/focus/):

```
$(function() {
     $(".bx").focus(function(e) {
         var selectedval = this.value,
             selectedtype = this.id;
         …
     });
});
```